# In Docker after install a Global module the module is not found

Tags: docker

I created a simple Dockerfile to install some node tools globally.

```
FROM node:10.9.0
RUN npm -g config set user root
RUN npm -g install --unsafe-perm merge-yaml
RUN mkdir -p /workDirectory
WORKDIR /workDirectory
```

Building the image i expect that merge-yaml will be availabe on any path (globally)

```
docker build -t  thisisme/devtools .
```

But using as exec the command is not found

```
docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/workDirectory thisisme/devtools merge-yaml

docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"merge-yaml\": executable file not found in $PATH".
```

If I enter into the container and verify the module is not added globally:

```
docker run --rm -it  thisisme/devtools /bin/bash
root@e77027bb2f57:/workDirectory# merge-yaml
bash: merge-yaml: command not found
```

I am sure that i am doing wrong because, in interactive mode install globally and not works (as I expected)

```
root@e77027bb2f57:/workDirectory# npm install -g merge-yaml
+ merge-yaml@1.1.0
updated 1 package in 0.584s
root@e77027bb2f57:/workDirectory# merge-yaml
bash: merge-yaml: command not found
root@e77027bb2f57:/workDirectory#
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Either I don't really get it or I'm missing something... You are installing an **npm package** and you are then trying to see if it is present by using its name as a **shell command**. Unless you actually create that command yourself (by e.g. creating an executable nodejs script that will use the above package and that you make available on the PATH), it does not look like the [module itself](https://github.com/skapoor/merge-yaml#readme) installs that command anywhere. Meanwhile, using `-g` installs the package in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` so that it is available globally.

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator for answer. But in my computer I installed globally and I can execute the command without creation of any node.js script.... that is what i was confused, why my computer add directly in path but docker container not.  But I think, I am mistaken and maybe I installed merge-yaml-cli in my laptop..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the command line, then you should install `merge-yaml-cli` instead.

Dockerfile :

```yml
FROM node:10.9.0
RUN npm -g config set user root
RUN npm -g install --unsafe-perm merge-yaml-cli
RUN mkdir -p /workDirectory
WORKDIR /workDirectory
```

After building the image, merge-yaml will then be available :

```
user@term:~/work $ docker run --rm -it quentin/test merge-yaml
Usage: /usr/local/bin/merge-yaml <options>

Options:
  -i, --inputs  Input files specified as glob file patterns   [array] [required]
  -o, --output  Output file                                  [string] [required]

Examples:
  /usr/local/bin/merge-yaml -i one.yml two/*.yml -o out.yml

Missing required arguments: i, o
```

Comment: Thanks guys, i was mistaken about the dependency that I installed. Now works.