# Getting 'module not found' when using Docker image as azure pipeline build agent

Tags: docker

I'm trying to use a Docker image I created as a build agent in an Azure pipeline. I'm using Azure DevOps Server 2019.

My Docker image is built with nodejs and my npm dependencies installed. I use the Docker image as a build agent for an Angular application.

This is the Dockerfile I use:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809-amd64

#Create app directory
WORKDIR /

# Install Chocolatey
RUN powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

#install node and npm
RUN choco install -y nodejs-lts --version 14.15.0
#install angular-cli
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN refreshenv

#Install app dependencies
COPY ./client/package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

CMD powershell
```

Here is the pipeline YAML I'm using:

```
trigger:
  none
resources:
  containers:
  - container: angulardocker
    image: angular-dev:1.0
    endpoint: Docker Hub

stages:
  - stage: Client
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        pool:
          name: Default
        container: angulardocker
        steps:
          - task: Npm@1
            displayName: 'Client Build'
            inputs:
              command: custom
              customCommand: run build -- --prod
              workingDir: client
          - task: CopyFiles@2
            displayName: 'Copy Client Build to Staging Directory'
            inputs:
              contents: '**'
              SourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/client/dist
              targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/client
          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: 'Publish Build Artifact - Client'
            inputs:
              pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/client'
              artifactName: 'Client'
```

When the pipeline runs, the Docker image is pulled from Docker Hub and initialized as a container successfully but throws an error when it gets to the 'npm run build --prod' build step.
This is the error message that appears:

```
; environment configs
cache = "C:\\__w\\6\\.npm"
userconfig = "C:\\__w\\6\\npm\\346.npmrc"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\ContainerAdministrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\__w\6\s\client
; HOME = C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

[command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run build -- --prod"
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\__w\6\s\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)

    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

The pipeline says it can't find the angular-cli node module. I ran the Docker image on its own and the node_modules folder does exist. I also tried changing the build step to '`ng build --prod'` using powershell and got this error: `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot locate the 'node_modules' directory.`

How do I get the pipeline to find the node_modules folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using npm’s **`--unsafe-perm`** switch in Dockerfile to see if it can work.

```
RUN npm -g install nodegit --unsafe-perm
```

To view more details, you can reference to the articles below:

- [When installation of global package using npm inside Docker fails](https://medium.com/@aguidrevitch/when-installation-of-global-package-using-npm-inside-docker-fails-b551b5dda389)
- [In Docker after install a Global module the module is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64133397/in-docker-after-install-a-global-module-the-module-is-not-found)

Comment: I added the install nodegit step right before I install angular-cli. Still got the error: `Cannot locate the 'node_modules' directory`.

Comment: Hi @mdailey77,

How about move the line `COPY ./client/package*.json ./` to after the line `WORKDIR /`. For example: `WORKDIR / <br> COPY ./client/package*.json ./`

Comment: I moved `COPY ./client/package*.json ./` to right after `WORKDIR /` and still got the same error.